# Is it a good idea to read a file's lines with a java 8 parallel streams?

Tags: java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream

Is it a good idea to read a file's lines with a java 8 parallel streams?
Every line is an URL, so the task is to

1. Read an URL
2. Connect to the appropriate URL address
3. Save the resource to an appropriate folder

Sometimes parallel streams using lead to mysterious bugs, so is it the straight case to use parallel streams?

Comment: No, it's definitely a terrible idea. Parallel streams are meant to use CPUs in parallel, not to perform IO tasks...

Comment: hmm, IO tasks could be performed asynchronously  BTW

Comment: Yes, I agree. Actually, it's a very good thing to perform several IO tasks *concurrently*. But parallel streams are not meant for IO. They are designed to take advantage of cases when you need to perform CPU intensive calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if your file does not have multiple lines, you might not benefit at all from parallel processing, for two reasons: 1) because all that parallel infrastructure is not cheap and 2) because a stream does not known how many lines a `File` has. As such, it will read lines and create a buffer for every Spliterator ( chunk ), IIRC it starts with `1024` lines and add 1024 and so on... So parallel might turn up to be very expensive with most probably no benefit in such a case. If on the other hand you have huge files... Measure to understand if you really need `parallel`

Also note that you are going to do some IO and parallel is not that of a good idea for that.